# Change Email Sender in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

I send emails from my website and i want to have special title for it in mail boxes as i show in below picture. When i send an email it show it's address as title. how can i show a special terms as title in emailing from asp.net. for example i want to show this:

Avestia Publishing  instead of no-reply@avestia.com

[image]
I use this code for emailing:

```
bodyMsg.Append("<p>Dear admin,</p>" + RadioButtonList_Prefix.SelectedItem.Text + " " + name.Text + " " + lastname.Text + " has registered in submissin system as an author.<p></br></br></br>Best regards,</p><p>Avestia Publishing</p>");

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Body = bodyMsg.ToString();

            msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            //  msg.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(TextBox2.Text);
            msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@avestia.com");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(*****));
            SmtpClient mailsender = new SmtpClient();

            mailsender.Host = "SmtpClient.gerbera.arvixe.com";

            mailsender.Port = 587;
            mailsender.EnableSsl = true;
            mailsender.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("no-reply@avestia.com", "classaspnet");

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            //Literal1.Text = "<script>alert(' ')</script>";
            smtp.Send(msg);
```

can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@avestia.com");
```

To this:

```
msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@avestia.com", "Avestia Publishing");
```

Comment: That's odd.  Wonder if Yahoo! does some sort of caching for emails it's run into before..